# Task management for team

Tags: project-management

I'm looking for a web application to manage tasks (not necessary programming-oriented) for a small team. It must be easy to setup and maintain, and I don't look for an SaaS solution. It must offer file upload and mail users in case of a change. There is hundred of solutions available but most are too complex for what we want or are not "stable" (not updated since a long time, not very well programmed). i was wondering if stack overflow's folks have some recommendations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

lighthouse - http://lighthouseapp.com/

-or-

gemini - http://www.countersoft.com/home.aspx

Answer (score 2):

We had a very similar requirement and after much searching we eventually decided on [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/).

Does all that you require and more.  Setup couldn't be easier if you use one of the [Bitnami](http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine) stacks.  We went down the virtual image route as we had a VMWare server - but installers for existing platforms are also available.

Comment: a bit too much development oriented  for me

Answer (score 1):

I tried Basecamp some time ago but I don't need a web based solution. But it was pretty good.

http://basecamphq.com/

Answer (score 1):

Redmine is a great project management, used by many open source projects. It is also quite actively maintained and really stable.

It's worth mentioning that even though Redmine is software oriented, it can easily be used as a project management software. All you have to do is ignore all the parts about repositories and you have a full-fledged project management software.

http://www.redmine.org/